# Use an array in Excel to return a list while also ignoring results in a third column

Tags: arrays, excel, list

Seeking to build an array that produces values from the list in column B.  However there is a twist - I want the array to also consider the third column to make sure it is 'not blank' before producing the list.

So:

Column A     Column B     Column C 
Ashish          234                      blank/null 
Sanjay          334                      good1 
Pongal               434                      good2 
Ashish               534                      good3 
Rajesh               634                     good4 
Suresh               734                     blank/null 
Ashish               834                     good5

Target= Ashish

Results should be:

534 
834

The 234 result should be skipped because it was blank.  Any idea how to pull it off?  Array code in excel is preferred but VBA is acceptable too.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is my starting code:  {=if(iserror(index($A$1:$B$7,small(if($A$1:$A$7="Ashish",row($A$1:$A$7)),row(1:1)),2)),"",index($A$1:$B$7,small(if($A$1:$A$7="Ashish",row($A$1:$A$7)),row(1:1)),2))}  but it gives me 234, 534, 834.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the "Ashish" with a cell reference to a cell that contains the name to look for.  Adjust ranges to suit and you will need to array enter with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$8="Ashish",IF($C$2:$C$8<>"",ROW($B$2:$B$8))),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Comment: Yes the code is more elegant than mine and works great!  My workaround was to replace the names with an "if c="","",name".